# RhoMobile framework worth looking at?

Tags: mobile, frameworks, rhomobile

I have been looking framworks for developing mobile apps and i have been told to work on `rhomobile framework` but i did google and i found very limited resources and tutorial... my apps are bit complicated and at this point i am not even sure rhomobile framework is good choice....

do you guys think it will worth investing time in learning?

any suggestions?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirements. If your application is data centric then I highly recommend Rhomobile, and If your application has less data and more static page then better use Native frameworks. 
You can quickly start with following resources http://rhomobile.com/resources/

Comment: how difficult is to learn? and where do i find the resources? and how difficult is to add controls like for calendar or player or graph? - any advice.

Comment: It is easy to learn you can quickly start with following resources:
 1.) Rhomobile Webinars
 2.) rhomobile doc
 3.) Rhomobile Beginner's Guide by pact Publication

It support native calendar provided by devices. http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#pim-calendarevents

For Player: for these you don't have much options but you can have look at http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#media-support

For Graphs you can use any Jquery graph library  like JQplot.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, and i am exploring and its all new to me and i looked at the http://rhomobile.com/webinars/ but the video resoulation is hard to see what is being typed or talking about... do you know any site that dedicated screen cast? i looked at your book cursory and i am still not on the track...

Comment: The best resource to start is http://docs.rhomobile.com/ But if you need some sample example you can check these examples: 1.) Twitter:  http://itsallaboutruby.blogspot.com/2010/10/creating-rhodes-application-which-will.html 2.)You tube http://itsallaboutruby.blogspot.com/2011/09/rhomobile-ipad-example-you-tube-client.html

Comment: Native framework i mean to say you individually build for each phone using iphone SDK, Android SDK, Blackberry JDE etc

Comment: @AbhishekNalwaya I read your book Rhomobile beginners guide. i want to know that is it possible that to develop the project in rhoStudio and then extending it using xcode. means for further development of that project i will be using xcode not rhoStudio. How will I link the models or view created in RhoStudio to the view controllers in the xcode. I am new to RhoStudio.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some knowledge in ruby it is not very difficult to start using rhodes, but it will always depend on your requirements and on how much time you want to invest to develop apps for different OS.

I have found Rhomobile very easy to follow. Of course it is limited as it is a relatively new framework, but you can get very good help on their [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/rhomobile).

I have developed on iOS and Android, and I must say I hated Objective C. Android with Java was more familiar and easier for me, but still, it is not compared to doing one app that works for all (even though you have to make dome minor tweaks for each OS).

One thing I did have problems developing in Rhomobile was working with maps. Rhomobile's Maps have different limitations depending on the OS of deployment.

Anyways, specially if you are working by yourself, I would recommend experimenting with Rhomobile. I believe you will get your job done faster that developing for each one (Objective C is a nightmare!)

Comment: thank you very much for the reply and  encouragement and if you know any screen cast or blog please post it here.

Comment: I only used rhomobile's webinars and google group to develop. If I can help you with any questions I'll be happy to do it

Comment: ihave posted number of questions on rhomobile tag

Answer (score 0):

One thing I love about Rhomobile Rhodes framework is their support for those old Symbian S40 phones, although they are not the mainstream phones today but still those platforms need to be supported in many enterprise apps